# Fitting data with restrictions on the output

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a simple set of x, y data points in form of x and y data lists. They represent intensity correction factors for given wavelengths that were computed experimentaly in the 400-700nm range. Unfortunately, I need data in the range 300-900nm, but can't experimentally obtain it. I am trying to fit the data with some type of function (can be polynomial, exponential, logarithmic,...). The output should be a list of values the function evaluates to in the 300-900 x-range with a 0.5 step, but each of the values should not be smaller than 0.1 or larger than 5 (or some arbitrary numbers). The function will not be the one which best describes the data, but it will be one which best describes it while only having values within the bounds in the full range.

I am currently using simple polynomial functions, but they always behave badly outside of the known range. The problem is worse since the correction factors don't only depend on wavelength, but also on other parameters, so on different occasions they will have a different dependence on wavelength and there is not one generic function which works well for it. That is why I am approaching it with a polynome using np.polyfit.

I just want to know if there is a way to constrain the minimization by imposing a minimum and maximum value (same ones) for all the points of the resulting list of function values in the 300-900 x-range. My experience with scipy.optimize.minimize or curve_fit is limited and to my knowledge it only works for imposing bounds on the parameters or constraints on the relations of the parameters, which I fail to see how it would help, and aksing chat GPT about it repeatedly also didn't result in much.

I would be thankful for any advice, documentation or reference to a similar solved problem. I'd share some examples of what I've tried, but what I am missing is not implementation but the knowledge of the needed tools.

Comment: SO needs code for this to be on topic.